# How to use Firestore with React-native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using

> @React-native 0.61.4

and

> @firebase 7.4.0

Functions like

> Firebase.auth()

seems to work ok but when I use

> Firebase.firestore()

nothing happens. This is my code:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';

export const fetchUser = (userId) => async dispatch => {

    await Firebase.firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
        alert('.............')

    }).catch(error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));

};
```

It does not enter the then() and print the dots nor enter() the catch and print the error. I have also tried other options like react-native-firebase and that nether works because of the version of ios 13 and react-native

Answer (score 0):

Use @react-native-firebase/firestore instead.

It's an abstraction on @firebase/firestore.
[See guide here](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/firestore/quick-start)